# Strange second argument passed to event handler (always undefined)

Tags: event-handling, reactjs

I've attached event listener with `onClick` property like this:

```
<a href="#" onClick={function (event) {
    console.log(arguments.length);   // prints 2
    // arguments[0] = SyntheticEvent - it's ok
    // arguments[1] = undefined - what is this???
}}>Click me</a>
```

The event listener called with 2 arguments: synthetic event and strange undefined value.

I think, normal behavior is when handler called with a *single* param - event object.

> Windows 10. Chrome 53. React version - 15.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument is the key which react gives to elements when you didn't provided your key.

React will automatically use an increasing integer number for the key.

> React will determine whether it is the same component or not based on that key.

[Here is more info.](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/10/react-dot-js-and-dynamic-children-why-the-keys-are-important/)

In [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1163/) you can see if you click on first link that key is 0.0 and if you click on the second one that key is 0.2 because `<br/>` has a key of 0.1.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I look your fiddle. But I've mentioned that there is an older version of React (0.13.1). I currently use latest (15.3.2). In this version React does not attach keys to every element with `data-reactid="*"` attribute. So I can assume that this problem come in new versions.

Comment: I've just checked your thesis. No, that argument is not a key. I've specified it with the prop `key={123}` on link element, but it still undefined.